# How do I scanf the first 2 digits of a number in C?

Tags: c

For example, an input would be 2095 and I want 20 as an output. Thanks.

Comment: See 'width' in the docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always scan 2 characters into an int

```
scanf("%2d", &num);
```

or if you already have the number

```
while (num >= 100) num /= 10;
```

This will give you the first 2 digits in number form.

Answer (score 3):

You can write, for example:

```
scanf("%2d", &i);
```

(where the `2` "specifies the maximum field width"); see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
scanf("%2d", &i);
```